# Entity Framework Client/Server needs to share the same key ID

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework

Im a student developing a project where I use Entity Framework 5.0 CodeFirst to provide my application's with embedded databases. I have a server and a client application which have the exact same local database, but in two seperate solutions.

The databases have a Project table, which can have Drawings, and Drawings can have some components on it. Therefore if the client want to query for drawings on a specific project on the server I have made a method called:

```
GetDrawings(int ProjectId)
{
     var result = suedocode: get all drawings;
}
```

which should get all drawings for a specific project.

My big problem is. Lets say that the server have 10 projects with the following id's:
ProjectId: 1, ..., ProjectId: 10.

If my client application query for the project on the server with ProjectId = 3 and saves that on the client's local db, the ProjectId get a new id which is ProjectId = 1, because its the first project stored in the clients db. When i now wants to query for drawings on my newly stored project and uses the associated ProjectId, I actually gets drawings associated with the project on the server with ProjectId=1.

So the big question is, is i possible the let the server generate the Id's and the those exact Id's are used when the client saves the projects. So when ProjectId=4 on server get stored on the client's db the id is ProjectId=4, even tho it's the first project store in the table.

Hope i explained it my problem so it's possible to understand.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the server generated IDs locally, but turn off the IDENTITY functionality for the local key.

or...

Consider using a guid/uniqueidentifier as your primary key.  It can be assigned at runtime and stored when appropriate.

There is [alot of discussion](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&noj=1&site=webhp&source=hp&q=uniqueidentifier%20vs%20identity&oq=uniqueidentifier%20vs%20identity) if you like to compare opinions and strategies.